# show that $\det(A)=0$ in this case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

(a) Let $x$ and $y$ be $n\times 1$ matrices, $n \ge 1$, and let $A=xy^T$. Show that $\det(A)=0$.

(b) Explain why the statment in part (a) is false if $n=1$.

Comment: Consider a non-zero vector $u$ orthogonal to $y$, and then?

Comment: Are you familiar with the *rank* of a matrix? If yes, what is the rank of $xy^T$? How many should it be to have nonzero determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$y^T=(y_1,\cdots, y_n)$$
so 
$$A=xy^T=(y_1x\cdots y_nx)$$
and then we see that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent so $\det A=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the (a) part, if $v \neq 0$ is a vector orthogonal to $y$, it implies $<v, y> = y^Tv = 0$

So there is a non-null solution and $\det(A) = 0$

Does exists a vector $v \neq 0$? Well if $y$ has $n > 1$ component, then there exists $n-1$ vectors linearly independent of $y$, and then applying graham schmidt you can find one that is orthogonal.

If $n=1$ then $x$ and $y$ are numbers, and so $A$ is also a number and $\det(A) = A \neq 0$ if $x, y \neq 0$

(basically there are no vectors orthogonal to $y$ because all vectors are generated by $y$)